# Ajax post error with no futher information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need help with this stuff. Chrome doesn't have this problem, only Firefox. When I submit form, ajax creates tasks. My mysql queries ain't got any problems, I added tons of

> if not working write mysql error into file

But all are successful. So here is the error 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYq4L.jpg how to find out what the hell is this? My code of ajax is pure empty here it is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/modules/projects/ajax/ajax_import.php',
    data: {
        data: array,
        id: projectNow,
    }
});
```

Thats it.

Comment: How are you triggering the ajax event? With $('#button').click(function(e) {}) ?

Comment: @opp It's function and I've added onclick="injectAjax();"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First check **ajax_import.php** is available at this location or not.

/modules/projects/ajax/ajax_import.php

If file is exist at this location then just clear all content from there and just write test content as below.

```
<?php 
    echo "testing";
?>
```

Comment: Same error. I've tried changing file name. Still the same. I've went directly to that page and it exists. WHAT ELSE CAN BE WRONG? ;(

Comment: I cant fix it without more information. I need to look whole code. sorry buddy.